# calculating euclidean distance for Luv values between 2 pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, euclidean-distance

In opencv c++ I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the euclidean distance between point i,j and all points within a 3x3 kernel. This is to create a contrast map of saliency from the Luv color space. I've also tried the norm function to no avail. I'm very confused as to how to solve this problem and would appreciate some feedback.

```
  Mat tmp1 = MeanShift_Luv.clone();

  int big_theta = 3; // kernel size / neighborhood to perform convolution on

  Mat gradient_1 = Mat::zeros(tmp1.rows, tmp1.cols, CV_64FC3);
  for (int i = 0; i < tmp1.rows; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < tmp1.cols; j++){     
      double dist = 0;
      for (int m = -big_theta / 2; m < big_theta / 2; m++){  

          for(int n = -big_theta /2; n < big_theta / 2; n++){
              if (m == 0 || n == 0) continue;
              if (i + m < 0 || i + m >= tmp1.rows) continue;
              if (j + n < 0 || j + n >= tmp1.cols) continue;

              /* unsure what to do at this part
              Point a(i,j);
              Point b(i+m, j+n);
              */ 
         }
     }
     gradient_1.at<Vec3d>(i,j) = dist;
   }
```

Comment: You've some indentation problem... Try to fix it, a badly closed block might be the cause of your problem. By the way: What should your code do? What does *effectively* you code do? It makes no use to post it if you don't explain this...

Comment: I fixed the style problem, that's not what's causing my issue at the moment. I commented in the original post where the euclidean distance calculation was supposed to go.

Comment: A distance formula computes the distance between two points, but you're using 9 - you need to be more specific about what you're trying to do. And I think you want your loops to be `n <= big_theta / 2`.

Comment: i've since abandoned this method for what i was trying to do, but for anyone interested.

https://ideone.com/SBw0mu